# Deleting and updating tables in Microsoft SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using the following code to add items to the table but I have troubles deleting or updating items in the table. I am trying commands like

```
delete from MyTable 
values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "',)";
```

and the command is accepted but the item is not deleted.

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into MyTable values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "',)";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Item inserted");
```

It is a bit hard to find resources since google just shows, sql or mysql when I try to search for a solution.

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: `and the command is accepted but the item is not deleted` INSERT, inserts data.  DELETE deletes data.  Are you expecting to have data deleted from an INSERT statement?

Comment: Why do you think an **`INSERT`** statement would *delete* a row? `INSERT` *inserts* rows. It's `DELETE` that *deletes* rows... Unsurprisingly, too, an `UPDATE` *updates* rows.

Comment: You should show the code you attempted for updates and deletes if that's what your question pertains to.  Also there are tons of examples if you search `SqlCommand Update`

Comment: First you should use SqlParameter to avoid SQL injection attack.
And next, as some people said, an INSERT only insert rows in table.
If you want do delete, you have to use DELETE SQL statement, if you want to update, you have to use UPDATE sql statement

Comment: "have troubles" isn't an error message or problem statement. But as others have said it's not clear why you'd expect an INSERT to delete anything. Any basic SQL tutorial would explain

Comment: Thanks for the update. `delete from MyTable values...` is not valid SQL. Your C# should 
 be throwing an exception because the SQL Server will be complaining about it. DELETE has different syntax than INSERT. UPDATE also has different syntax, for that matter. Stop guessing and [read the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - or consult any basic SQL Server tutorial, e.g. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-delete/.

Comment: `It is a bit hard to find resources`.... are you sure? [Click here](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+delete) . What exactly have you been searching for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you expect an SQL command based on the `INSERT` keyword to delete a record?

```
using var con = new SqlConnection(" ... ");
using var cmd = con.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = @"
 DELETE 
 FROM MyTable 
 WHERE MyColumn= @SomeValue";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
// No need to call con.Close();. The using directive takes care of it.
```

Pay special attention to how I used a query parameter. The string concatenation technique in the question is **NEVER** okay, and is the easiest way I've seen to find out a year from now you were hacked six months ago.

To change (update) a record, you must write an `UPDATE` query:

```
using var con = new SqlConnection(" ... ");
using var cmd = con.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = @"
 UPDATE MyTable 
 Set SomeColumn = @SomeValue 
 WHERE SomeOtherColumn = @SomeOtherValue";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeOtherValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
// No need to call con.Close();. The using directive takes care of it.
```

The thing to understand about this is you do not delete or update a record by specifying all the fields in a `VALUES()` clause, as you would with an `INSERT`. Instead, you use a `WHERE` clause and only need to include enough for the conditional expressions to identify which row(s) you want to change or delete. An `UPDATE` statement will then further specify what to change via the `SET` clause.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And what is the use of the @SomeValue String? The column is already specified in the command so what do I use @  for?

Comment: That is a placeholder for a parameter value. It is the correct way to include data into your SQL statement. It's **important**, because it performs better than string concatenation (allows for cached query plans) and because it protects you from sql injection issues.

Comment: @Tensora See the new paragraph I just added to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I understand, but can I dyanmically change that value with something like: var str1 = "Baseball";        ...Set Game = @+str1+...    and so on?

Comment: Hello, I have problems understanding the @ sign.

Comment: We get the error "cannot convert String to to Int32"

Comment: If it's not going to an `int` column, don't use `SqlDbType.Int`.

Comment: Remember, in t SQL variable names start with an `@`. All the `@` sign does here is indicate a variable name in the SQL command. As for the baseball example, the SQL looks like `Set Game = @Game`, and the C# looks like `var str1 = "Baseball"; cmd.Parameters.Add("@Game", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = str1;`. So the `Parameters.Add()` line maps the C# variable value to the SQL variable (`@Game`).